# proper virtual operator= overloading usage

Tags: c++

the following concept works, 
but, in cWorld::main(), i would like to get rid of the :

if (instanceOf) cast

elseif (instanceOf) cast

elseif (instanceOf) cast

elseif (instanceOf) cast

elseif (instanceOf) cast

etc...

1) knowing iData has to stay blind to what cDataChar & cDataString are.

2) knowing i don't search for an answer using templates.

3) I want a solution that properly redirects the call to the right virtual operator=
Thanks.

```
//---------
class iData
{
    virtual const iData&    operator=(const cDataChar&  data) = 0;
    virtual const iData&    operator=(const cDataString& data) = 0;
}
//----------------------------
class cDataChar : public iData
{
    char _data;

    virtual const iData&    operator=(const cDataChar&  data) 
                            { [...implementation...] }
    virtual const iData&    operator=(const cDataString& data)
                            { [...implementation...] }
}
//----------------------------
class cDataString : public iData
{
    string _data;

    virtual const iData&    operator=(const cDataChar&  data) 
                            { [...implementation...] }
    virtual const iData&    operator=(const cDataString& data)
                            { [...implementation...] }
}
//=============================
void
cWorld::main(shared<iData> data1, shared<iData> data2)
{
    if (data2->instanceOf(cDataChar))   
    {
        auto dataChar = static_pointer_cast<cDataChar>(data2);
        (*data1) = (*data2);
    }
    else if (data2->instanceOf(cDataString))    
    {
        auto dataString = static_pointer_cast<cDataString>(data2);
        (*data1) = (*data2);
    }

    // here if i do only (*data1) = (*data2);
    // it doesnt find the right iData::operator= 
    // and goes into the default one.
}
```

Comment: Using an operator like `=` for this violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: It seems you are trying to implement [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). The usual approach to this is the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Is `Clone` sufficient ? or left side is really shared ?

Comment: Visitor pattern worked fine, thanks.